# How to get data from a bluetooth device that is not visible?

Tags: bluetooth

I just bought a Fitbit One which includes Bluetooth 4.0 to sync with mobile devices. Currently libfitbit does not include support for bluetooth syncing, so I would like to see how much data I can get out of the device that I can pass onto the libfitbit devs so that they can explore bluetooth support.

I ran:

```
hcitool scan
```

which unfortunately did not return any devices. I also used blueman to scan for devices and nothing was found either.

Therefore I am assuming that the bluetooth radio in the device is not visible by default.

Can anyone recommend any ways to get data out of the device that could be helpful?

Answer (score 1):

The reason you were not able to find it in hcitool scan is because the FitBit One is a bluetooth LE device.

You need to use `hcitool lescan`. Even then, your hardware needs to support it. Further, connecting to it wasn't even possible on my machine (lenovo p500 'ideapad') using hcitool lecc or gatttool --interactive (and then 'connect')

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be possible if you know you can find unique ID for the bluetooth radio of device.(May be on device manuals/box ??)

I tried with my pantech android phone, and I could find name of my device using

hcitool name bluetooth_id

I dont have much knowledge on this, this is what I got so far.